How to random a number depend on length of a given sring Python
I want to random an integer from a range which the probability correlates with the number of tokens string.
For example:
Given max possible number of tokens = 64. Random integer's range is from 0 to 7
Given a string has 46 tokens.
I want to use the function random.choices([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], weights=[..], k=1
and set the weights something like: [0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2]
I just give an example for the weights, I mean its weights need to be correlated with the len(tokens) and max_len_token=64. Here is 46 compare to 64, so it gives more probs on 4 and 5, but still give a chance for others just decrease by some reasonable ratio

How about doing it in two steps? First write a function #tokens => weights distribution array. And then use that array to generate the number as shown above.

Ja, I mean how to compute the weight distribution given the number of tokens? Like I don't want to use if else statement and set raw number, I'm trying to think a formula

Have a look at a Triangular distribution. It will return a float, so you'll need to do some adjustment to turn it into an int, and take care with the extreme limits (might be easiest to have the min and max of the distribution as +/- 0.5 or 1.0 from your actual limits, then maybe discard invalid results) https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.triangular.html#numpy.random.Generator.triangular

It might be best to refactor your requirement. If the problem is "How do I get random integer values from an unknown distribution that has a lower limit, upper limit, and a peak (mode)?" then the random.triangular method might be suitable.
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_triangular_weighted(min_val, max_val, token_len, max_len_token):
    assert token_len <= max_len_token
    # Find modal value--it's token_len/max_token_len through the set
    mode_value = (max_val - min_val) * (token_len / max_len_token) + min_val
    rand_value = random.triangular(min_val, mode_value, max_val+1)
    
    return int(rand_value)

plt.hist([random_triangular_weighted(0, 7, 46, 64) for _ in range(100000)],
         bins=range(9),
         align='left')
plt.show()



Thank you! Yes it looks like what I want.

Maybe define a function with the parameter being the length of the random string you want to generate. Random numbers are obtained by random.randint(a, b) method,
